# How to place dummy image in CircleAvatar before retrieval of the main image from cloud firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Placing a dummy image inside a CircleAvatar. The dummy image is replaced by the main image which is fetched from cloud firestore database.

Here I am trying to make Profile-image which contain User-Profile for that I have used CircleAvatar which will store image in it. Retrieval of image is done well & working properly. But now I have mixed up with some "Question" if technically the  profile URL is not saved in firestore database then it will throw error. So to stop the prevention of the error I need to use dummy image which will be replaced by the main image fetched from cloud firestore database.

Now the Q:- How can I place dummy image inside a CircleAvatar and that dummy image is replace by the main image

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot post;
  DetailPage({this.post});

  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Detail'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body:
         Form(
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius:73 ,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: new SizedBox(
                          width: 125,
                          height:125,
                          child: Image.network(widget.post.data['image'],height: 108,fit: BoxFit.fill,),

                        ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),

 ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look in Future Builder

Comment: @S.Ramjit .how can I do this and where shall I place dummy image URL and how can I should inside CircleAvatar. Can u pls explain me with code .

Answer (score 1):

You can Look into this. this supports the functionality you require.

https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

you can put any widget in the placeholder. and it also supports erros indicators

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```